# Bootstrap navbar not showing but hover state working?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I was just going to start a guided project but I got stuck because Navbar was not getting displayed
The hover state works when I uncomment the links in the navbar.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Comapany Website</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Nav Bar -->
    <nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <!-- <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="images/" alt="">
                </a>
            </div>
            <ul class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div> -->
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

From bootstrap documentation: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/

> .collapse.navbar-collapse for grouping and hiding navbar contents by a
> parent breakpoint.

Secondly open the console and there you can see errors. Probably you got an error while loading the resources i.e. styles.css or the image you have inside the nav-bar header.

If you delete the class collapse and comment the resources you will see the navigation bar. I suggest you to start from checking the resources.